# How can I read multiple xml files from two different folders in Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have multiple files to read and write from two different directories with same parent path.
Is it possible to select particular directory in "org.springframework.batch.item.file.**MultiResourceItemReader**" if one of the directory has no files to read?

```
<!-- multi xml reader -->
    <bean id="multiResourceReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader">
        <property name="resources" ref="vinFeedFileResouce" />
        <property name="delegate" ref="vinFeedReader" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="vinFeedFileResouce" class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource"    scope="step">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <ref bean="read_ONE" />
                <ref bean="read_TWO" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="read_ONE" class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource"  scope="step">
        <constructor-arg value="#{path_ONE}"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="read_TWO" class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource"  scope="step">
        <constructor-arg value="#{path_TWO}"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

I am getting following error for reader:

```
    [pool-1-thread-1](batch.listener.ModelMasterFailureListener:13)-Encountered error on Model master read
    org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:137)
        at org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader.read(MultiResourceItemReader.java:105)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:90)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProvider.read(FaultTolerantChunkProvider.java:87)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:108)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:367)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:214)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:143)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:103)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:68)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:386)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:264)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:76)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:367)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:214)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:143)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:250)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:281)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:114)
        at com.ahm.ngt.cbo.feed.batch.scheduler.RunScheduler.run(RunScheduler.java:80)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.MethodInvokingRunnable.run(MethodInvokingRunnable.java:65)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:51)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.vinFeedFileResouce' defined in class path resource [spring/batch/jobs/ca-vin-feed-config.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.io.File]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [java.io.File]: Failed to convert value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.io.File'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [java.io.File]: PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.FileEditor] returned inappropriate value
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:702)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:196)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1003)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:907)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:329)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:150)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:33)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:184)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.exists(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader.doOpen(StaxEventItemReader.java:187)
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:134)
        ... 45 more
```

Answer (score 1):

If you see the source code of `FileSystemResource`, you would find the constructor can take either File or String not list of files or String. You can write custom Resource Reader to read the files from multiple directory. Here is an example

```
    <bean id="multiResourceReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader">
        <property name="resources" value="#{myResourceReader.read()}" />
        <property name="delegate" ref="vinFeedReader" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myResourceReader" class="com.kp.swasthik.MyResourceReader">
        <property name="resource" value="file:///path1/*.txt, file:///path2/*.txt"></property>
    </bean>
```

The ResourceReader class.

```
public class MyResourceReader {

    private String resource;

    public String getResource() {
        return resource;
    }

    public void setResource(String resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    public Resource[] read(){

        List<Resource> resources = new ArrayList<>();
        if(resource == null || resource.isEmpty()){
            return new Resource[]{};
        }
        PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        Arrays.stream(resource.split(",")).forEach(v->{
            try {
                Collections.addAll(resources, resolver.getResources(v));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        return resources.toArray(new Resource[0]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch to annotation based configuration. There you could add all your resources (from different dirs) to the reader:

```
@Bean
public ItemReader<?> reader() {
   Resource[] res = ... //get eg using PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver multiple times on different dirs

   MultiResourceItemReader<?> r = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
   r.setResources(res);
   return r;
}
```